# Effects of frequently turning on and off power in the grid

Tags: transformer, transmission-line

What would happen to the infrastructure (transformer, transmission line etc) If I would turn on and off power frequently? Will it cause wear and tear? If so how? And how much?
Also the effects of lowering/increasing the power grid?

Answer (score 1):

**Massive** changes in load may require starting up or shutting down generation equipment. Rather than start up a fossil fuel plant, it's more economical to use [load levelers](https://new.abb.com/distributed-energy-microgrids/applications/energy-storage-applications/load-leveling) to improve efficiency and reduce operating cost.

Changes made by a residential load, though, are negligible. The only effect you might notice is a slight dimming of lights on turning a large appliance (or *brightening* of lights on the opposite side of a split-phase line). You might destroy the appliance switch or relay contact if you cause an arc, but that's considered normal wear-and-tear.